# Will you mind [mine/my/me] interrupting you?

Tags: sentence-construction

Suppose a person is speaking and if I want to interrupt him, what can I say?

> 1)Will you mind mine interrupting you?
>
> 2)Will you mind me interrupting you?
>
> 3)Will you mind my interrupting you?

What is the correct construction?

Comment: I would say, "Do you mind if I interrupt?"

Comment: Of those three, number two seems natural and normal. One and three seem unnatural, while three also seems unnecessarily stiff and formal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option (1) is straightforwardly wrong. Don't use it.

Option (2) and (3) are both valid, but are a little stilted. A more natural way would be to say:

> **Would** you mind **if I** interrupt you there?
>
> **Would** you mind **if I** interrupt you for a second?
>
> **Can** I interrupt you for a minute?

If you're interrupting to add something or disagree with the sentence you can also say:

> **Can** I just stop you there?

And if you're interrupting an unrelated discussion to get someone's attention:

> Excuse me, Mr Johnson. Can I have a moment of your time? (*esp. to a more senior person*)
>
> Excuse me, Mr Smith. Can I have a quick word with you?

**Will** would normally be used by a native speaker to ask strictly about the future:

> **Will** you mind if I interrupt your meeting tomorrow? I'm going to be late.

Answer (score 1):

*Mine* is never used as adjective or modifier. You can say "That is your dog; this is mine." not "That is your dog; this is mine dog." In the last sentence, I should say "this is my dog" or use *mine* without *dog* (as in the previous sentence).

As said in ["Would you mind if I [do something]?" versus "Would you mind me [doing something]?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4606/would-you-mind-if-i-do-something-versus-would-you-mind-me-doing-something), "Will you mind my interrupting you?" is equivalent to "Will you mind if I interrupt you?" while "Will you mind me interrupting you?" refers to *me* personally and not to the action.